# SSIS - trying to pass formatted date to apply to file name

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, type-conversion

I have a SSIS package which has a SQL Task which formats the current date as DDMMMYY and passes it to a Data Flow Task which drops the date into the output file name

I keep getting

> Error: The type of the value (Int32) being assigned to variable
>   "User::DDMMMYY" differs from the current variable type (String).
>   Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are
>   strict, except for variables of type Object.

where is the Int32 coming from?

- ForcedExceutionValueType is String
- ParameterMappingDataType is VARCHAR

In Package Explorer the `ValueType` for the variable is `String`

Originally, the ForcedExecutionValueType was Int32 because that is what is in another SSIS package which is currently in Production (although the server it runs on is older than my Windows 10 machine)

Comment: what is the code in your execute sql task that is formatting the current date?  I'd be curious what data type it's returning.  It could be returning it as int which would be your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely one of two things.

1. SQL query returns an int when formatting to DDMMMYY. Cast/Convert that to Varchar in the query. `SELECT CONVERT(Varchar(8),'20191025')`
2. After the value is assigned to the SSIS variable you use it in an expression and try and concat another value or variable to that, that is of type Int32. Thus cast it in the expression as string or unicode. `(DT_STR,50,1252)@[User::Variable]`